# How to find which polylines completely include a given polyline?

Tags: algorithm, indexing, intersection, polyline

I want to find which polylines completely include a given polyline. There are some algorithms like Bentley-ottmann to find polyline intersection but I want those polylines which the given polyline is completely part of them.
I think representing each polyline with set of points and then remove those sets that don't have all points of given polyline can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the polylines are nondegenerate, to decide multidimensional polyline containment, you can partition the segments by slope–y-intercept pairs and solve several 1D problems. To solve the 1D problem, use a sweepline algorithm, processing the segment endpoints in sorted order and maintaining two flags, one for whether the sweepline intersects the container, one for whether the sweepline intersects the containee.